# questions for the candidate to ask during a skype faculty interview

Tags: faculty-application, interview, video-conference

What questions for the candidate to ask during an initial skype faculty interview? In the field of physical sciences.

Comment: This was asked recently but seems to have disappeared - shame...

Comment: Found this one : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/128041/72855

Comment: no, opposite question

Comment: Same... q that the candidate asks... If one q was about what the **interviewers** should ask then that would be opposite...

Comment: not really. interviewers ask how u r gonna teach. candidate cant ask this

Comment: not a duplicate

Comment: The interviewers can answer all the suggested questions in the answer given in the proposed duplicate... QED.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out what they want from you and ask it indirectly back.

For example if their research competence is in topic A of subfield B then say that you would be really keen to work A of subfield B (both in slightly different words but with the same meaning) and if there is sufficient critical mass at the department to do this and/or if the facutly would see it positive if you work on this topic.

You should basically feed them back (via questions using a slightly different wording) what they want you to be.

You can of course also ask some real questions on what you want to know but I guess you dont need a recommendation for that as you will know what you want to know.